# using a sub-string to identify file names in python

Tags: list, file, python-3.x

I am attempting to combine some files based on a similarity in file name.
I have a list of file names and based in a list of identifiers (sub-strings) I would like to combine the files.

I am using:

```
    for i in identifyList:
        print("\n".join(s for s in fileList if i.lower() in s.lower()))
```

when I run this script the files are printed in the correct order. However I cannot manage to use the product of this statement for anything but printing.
If I assign it to a variable and print the variable I get a list of:

```
    <generator object <genexpr> at longNumber>
```

I looked up how to use generators and found it very confusing.

any ideas?
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're getting generator objects somewhere because you're using generator expressions when you want to be using list comprehensions.

A list comprehension looks like `[some_expression(variable) for variable in some_iterable if some_condition(variable)]`. This produces a list, just like this explicit loop does:

```
result = []
for variable in some some_iterable:
    if some_condition(variable):
        result.append(some_expression(variable))
```

The advantage is that a list comprehension is all on one line and can be done anywhere an expression is allowed (like in a function call) without creating any extra variables.

A generator expression is very similar, it just replaces the list with an iterable generator object, which yields values one by one as they are needed in the iteration. This can be a big advantage if there are a lot of values to be produced and we don't want to keep them all in memory at the same time, or if we just don't care about keeping the list around.

The syntax for a generator expression is just to replace a list comprehension's `[]` square brackets with parentheses (or nothing if the generator expression is the only argument to a function, since then the function call's parentheses do the job already).

In your code, the call to `str.join` is using a generator expression as the (only) argument. If you want to do something else with the file names that match your condition (rather than joining them together), you may want to use a list comprehension instead:

```
for i in identifyList:
    matches = [s for s in fileList if i.lower() in s.lower())]
    # do something with the list here!
```